# clientHeight returning 0 for image when it set to width: 100% and not fixed height(responsive) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

`var image = document.createElement('img'); image.setAttribute('src', data.googleLogo); console.log(image.clientHeight); //0`
data.googleLogo --> image getting from Json Data,
image is *position: absolute* element to parent

Comment: Pls add a code snippet, so it can be understood better. Thanks

Comment: probably better to query `image.clientHeight` in the images `onload` event listener. you cannot figure out the calculated height before the image is loaded or enough metadata is present.

Comment: You can only read the height when the images is completely loaded.

Comment: tried using offsetHeight, still getting 0.

Comment: but using naturalHeight, then getting original image height, but not responsiv height

Comment: You do not show your full code - are you actually appending the image element to the DOM somewhere? If not then you will only get the naturalHeight (once sufficient of the image has been loaded) as there is no client or offset to calculate the height against. Could you be more explicit about what your problem is as at the moment things seem to be happpening as I'd expect.